# Spring-Boot Application: HTTPS Error on start-up: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https, keystore

We are trying to enable our spring-boot application to listen to HTTPS but are encountering the following error on application start up locally:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerManager.start(WebServerManager.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:40)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:243)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:258)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1290)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:606)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:390)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:331)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:344)
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1996)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:222)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:67)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97)
```

Here is what we have currently in our application.yml (which sits in our src/main/resources folder as does the keystore):

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store-type: 'PKCS12'
    key-store: 'classpath:***.p12'
    key-alias: '***'
    enabled: true
    protocol: 'TLS'
    key-store-password: '***'
```

However, if we remove the classpath argument and just place the keystore in the root directory of the project the application runs fine and there are no errors.

[spring boot https PKCS12 DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148884/spring-boot-https-pkcs12-derinputstream-getlength-lengthtag-111-too-big)

Have tried following solutions listed here but same error occurs.